# Postgres dump of only parts of tables for a dev snapshot

Tags: postgresql

On production our database is a few hundred gigabytes in size. For development and testing, we need to create snapshots of this database that are functionally equivalent, but which are only 10 or 20 gigs in size.

The challenge is that the data for our business entities are scattered across many tables. We want to create some sort of filtered snapshot so that only *some* of the entities are included in the dump. That way we can get fresh snapshots every month or so for dev and testing.

For example, let's say we have entities that have these many-to-many relationships:

- Company has N Divisions
- Division has N Employees
- Employee has N Attendance Records

There are maybe 1000 companies, 2500 divisions, 175000 employees, and tens of millions of attendance records. We want a replicable way to pull, say, the first 100 companies *and all of its constituent divisions, employees, and attendance records*.

We currently use pg_dump for the schema, and then run pg_dump with --disable-triggers and --data-only to get all the data out of the smaller tables. We don't want to have to write custom scripts to pull out part of the data because we have a fast development cycle and are concerned the custom scripts would be fragile and likely to be out of date.

How can we do this? Are there third-party tools that can help pull out logical partitions from the database? What are these tools called?

Any general advice also appreciated!

Answer (score 113, accepted):

On your larger tables you can use the COPY command to pull out subsets...

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ...) TO '/tmp/myfile.tsv'

COPY mytable FROM 'myfile.tsv'
```

[https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-copy.html)

You should consider maintaining a set of development data rather than just pulling a subset of your production.  In the case that you're writing unit tests, you could use the same data that is required for the tests, trying to hit all of the possible use cases.

Comment: I used this technique to great success to do the same thing as the OP.   For test runs I loaded COPY (SELECT .. ) TO .. constrained data into a "template" database and used CREATE DATABASE test_run_XX  TEMPLATE product_snapshot_XX.  I of course widdled the data down to a bare minimum so the product snapshot loaded and test db creation operations are fast enough to not be a team impediment.

Comment: Is there any way to make this work if you have multiple joined tables you want snapshots of? COPY FROM doesn't support importing multiple tables.

Comment: You're the man ... This makes things so easy for me, but for a different purpose. I used it to move data from the public schema to user specific schema in a multi-tenant app. Thanks !

Comment: Note this method does not update sequences on the copied tables so further inserts may violate primary key constraints.

Comment: I had to use `\copy` instead of `COPY` as well, because the latter was superuser-only. Fortunately everything else worked perfectly with no other changes in 9.1.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know about any software which already does this, but I can think of 3 alternative solutions. Unfortunately, they all require some custom coding.

1. Re-create all the tables in a separate schema, then copy into those tables only the subset of data you would like to dump, using `INSERT INTO copy.tablename SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ...` and dump that.
2. Write your own script for dumping data as SQL statements. I have used this approach in the past and it only took something like 20-30 lines of PHP.
3. Modify pg_dump so it accepts a condition along with the -t switch when dumping a single table.

Answer (score 8):

http://jailer.sourceforge.net/ does this.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense here. The OP asked specifically for the names of third party tools that do this. The essence of the answer is therefore only, "There is a third party tool called 'Jailer' that does this, at this URL." That link itself provides all that essential information; there is nothing else to add. If that link stops working, it can easily be inferred from the URL that "the program is called Jailer," so it would be redundant to add that.

Comment: Of course the link is now broken, and google turns up no alternative.

Comment: The link currently works for me, and Googling for "jailer postgres" turned up https://github.com/Wisser/Jailer , too.

Comment: Maybe if you added a helpful description of `how` you use this tool, we might be able to understand how it achieves the goal

Comment: Thank you for linking to this tool. It is the best tool for the job. Still maintained and active.