# Export only views in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Is there any way to export only the views from a Postgres schema?

I'm using Postgres 8.4.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have every view prefixed by certain prefix, you can use this command:

```
pg_dump -s -t 'prefix*' dbname > db.dump
```

or you can use `-t` switch as many as possible with names of views.

See [manpage for `pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html), on the end are examples.

Comment: Note that this exports the views, not the data that the views return. This is probably obvious to most, but it wasn't to me at first. To export the data returned by a view, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745105/postgres-dump-of-only-parts-of-tables-for-a-dev-snapshot

Comment: You'd probably favour dropping the `-s` and still using `pg_dump`, instead of going down the `COPY` route discussed on that question

Comment: I get error message `pg_dump: error: no matching tables were found` even after supplying wildcard!

Answer (score 23):

There's no direct flag to do this, but using our favourite query-the-schema-to-generate-a-command technique:

```
select string_agg( '-t ' || quote_ident(nspname) || '.' || quote_ident(relname), ' ' )
  from pg_class join pg_namespace on pg_namespace.oid = pg_class.relnamespace
  where relkind = 'v' and not (nspname ~ '^pg_' or nspname = 'information_schema');
```

This will generate a string that can be used with a pg_dump command, e.g.:

```
 -t media.duplicated_component -t adv.advert_view_distribution
```

Which you could then splice into a command line directly:

```
pg_dump $(psql -c "select string_agg(...etc...)" db) db
```

Comment: If you want to add materialized view, use `relkind in ('v', 'm')`.