# PostgreSQL: going to run out of IDs in integer columns

Tags: java, postgresql

## Problem

We are building a web application in Java on top of PostgreSQL. It's quite large and successful, and it should be able to run for a few more years at least.

Unfortunately, we (well, I) made a grave mistake in the early stages of the design process: **all the database IDs are integers, handed out from one shared sequence**.

[Java's max int is 2^31-1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), so approximately 2 billions. The same goes for [PostgreSQL's integer type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html). The system is currently eating up ~10k IDs every day, and the rate is going up as we gain new users.

One day, the IDs will run out and overflow.

## Question

We are looking for ways to fix the situation. Let's get the obvious one out of the way immediately: switching to Java's `long` and Postgres' `bigint` is a clean solution, but it's a **ton** of work. We need to postpone it as much as possible.

Some ideas we've had so far:

- Don't use one sequence for everything, give each table its own sequence.

  - Pros: this gives us up to N times more time, where N is the number of tables.
  - Cons: we like the fact that every row has a unique ID.
- Stop using sequence IDs for some of the tables. For example, a table with customer events doesn't really need an ID: `customer, timestamp` is a perfectly valid primary key.

  - Pros: some of our biggest ID-hogs could be changed this way.
  - Cons: nontrivial amount of work.
- Stop wasting IDs on empty records. This happens with some sub-tables, like customer contact information. Having the record always present makes the code simpler, but it means many customers have an empty contact information record stored.

  - Pros: some of our biggest ID-hogs could be fixed this way.
  - Cons: we lose the code simplicity.
- Every new table must use `long` / `bigint` with a new sequence.

  - Pros: at least we don't make it worse.
  - Cons: the contact surfaces with the rest of the code will be ugly.

**Under these constraints, what other approaches will delay the ID depletion?**

Comment: Yeah this is pain. Only two approaches, 1) Go with bigint and do the refactor (or) 2) Don't use sequence for everything. I lean more towards refactoring (other approaches, at some point you will exhaust the numbers). Will choose option two only in case where we know this application will be shutdown before numbers exhaust.

Comment: "it's a ton of work. We need to postpone it as much as possible." It will be two tons by the time you get to it if you postpone it. Bite the bullet and do it now.

Comment: I hate to say this, but as you're asking for opinions and options, you're probably going to get closed. I'm not going to do it, but somebody will.

Comment: @PaulTomblin no opinions, only options. There is no component of subjectivity here: all the options I have listed and the ones I hope for have a measurable and quantifiable effect on our problem.

Comment: We don't have enough information to really answer your question: we don't know why you "need to postpone it as much as possible"; we don't know what you are sacrificing if you do the refactoring (undoubtedly the right long-term approach); we don't know how big your codebase is, how many people you have to work on this, what tools you have at your disposal, what your test coverage is like etc etc. Any suggestion here will be based on incomplete information.

Comment: It seems difficult to consider a solution that will involve less effort than refactoring your code from `integer` to `long`. It also sounds like you made another few mistakes in the design (e.g. why store empty records when there's no contact info in a separate table or why share the same sequence across all tables?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switching to long is far from a clean solution. There's only one sensible option if you grow too large: UUIDs ([yes, PostgreSQL comes with uuid data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-uuid.html)).

At 128 bits its the size of 4 integers, but you don't want to go through whole application in few years and to all this again, do you? UUIDs will work when you grow too large and you need to shard your data. You won't be able to have a shared sequence then, that's why UUIDs make sense.

As a bonus you can even keep your unique property on each row.

---

Migration isn't that hard: adding a column with NULL in PostgreSQL is cheap, so you can first add a column and then do online migration in batches, where you update a few thousand records at a time, so you don't have downtime.

Then you can test the same code with both foreign keys. Does Java have anything similar to [laboratory](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/laboratory/0.1.0) or [scientist](https://github.com/github/scientist)?

Will it be a ton of work? Yes, but that's obviously a good sign, if you have an application that's so popular.

I also hope you've learned a lesson with using the same sequence for all the tables. Honestly - I don't really see added value in that. If you want to know where an object fits, you can also name the primary keys differently (eg. room_id, reservation_id, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Since asking this question, I have found a nice way to fix a half of the problem - the database side. So, for the future generations, here is the way to do it.

1. Find all the DB columns of type `integer` or `integer[]`. Check the results manually and remove columns of type, for example, `text[]`.

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM information_schema.columns cls
   JOIN information_schema.tables tbl ON cls.table_name = tbl.table_name
   WHERE
     cls.table_schema = '<my schema>'
     AND cls.data_type = 'integer' OR cls.data_type = 'ARRAY'
     AND tbl.table_type = 'BASE TABLE';
   ```
2. Prepare a data type change DDL for each of those columns:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE <one of the tables found> 
   ALTER COLUMN <one of its integral columns> 
   TYPE bigint;
   ```
3. This works beautifully, except for the `VIEW`s: they don't like me changing their return types. I need to re-create all of them - the sequence will be

   1. Drop all the views.
   2. Alter column types.
   3. Re-create all the views.
4. Stop the application, run the upgrade script from step 3, fix slow queries by running `VACUUM` and `ANALYZE` on all the tables.
5. Run tests and fix issues in the source code - for example, `bigint[]` cannot be cast to `integer[]`.

[How to export/backup `VIEW`s only?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8474097/5986572)