# Using pg_dump only get a portion of the data in the table ( e.g. created_on> "2020-01-01")

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I want use pg_dump dump partial data.what should I do.

Comment: like what you want whats you condition

Comment: You could use a user for whom "row level security" excludes the data that should not be dumped.

Comment: I read the document. dump the data  can not be added conditions.

Comment: Possible duplicate. Hello, @lethean, welcome to the SO club )) Check [theese answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745105/postgres-dump-of-only-parts-of-tables-for-a-dev-snapshot)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the copy command，like this:

```
\copy (SELECT * FROM "Object" WHERE created_on > '2020-01-01') TO '/Users/lethean/sql/object.csv' csv header;
\copy "Object" FROM '/Users/lethean/sql/object.csv' DELIMITER ',' csv header;
```